# express js cannot get / register

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I faced this issue where it gave me Cannot GET /register, but why get for the login.html is working and not register, do I'm missing something here ?  thank you guys for your help in advance. Here is the router

```
 const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router()
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const user = require('../models/user.js')
    router.get('/',(req,res)=>
        res.render('home')
    )
    router.get('/login',(req,res)=>
        res.render('login')
    )
    router.get('/register'),(req,res)=>{
        res.render('register')
    }

    router.post('/register'),  (req, res) =>{      
    };

    module.exports = router
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const indexRouter = require('./routes/route')
const sequilize = require('./database/db.js')
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
 }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
console.log(__dirname)
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use('/',indexRouter)
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('it started on 5000'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here

```
router.get('/register'),(req,res)=>{
        res.render('register')
    }
```

it should like

```
router.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
        res.render('register')
    }
```

you have added ")" after register